# Moving a SQL 2000 cube to SQL 2005

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, cubes

I have been tasked with moving a cube which is in SQL 2000 to SQL 2005.  It would appear that the Dimensions and Measures are all coming from one table.  Is this possible in SQL 2005 or do I need to restructure the data into multiple Dim/Fact tables, and is there any way to easily move a SQL 2000 cube into SQL 2005?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is such a thing as a fact-dimension in SSAS 2005. My guess is you would not need to restructure the data in order to migrate the cube. There is a migration wizard in SSMS that will migrate SSAS 2000 cubes over to SSAS 2005.

Comment: Thanks.. I simply right+mouse clicked on the 2005 analysis db in SQL Server Management Studio and chose "Migrate Database".  So easy.. Thanks.